# Split based on commas but ignore commas within double-quotes

Tags: python, string, list

I try to split strings based on commas with avoiding the ones within the double quotes.Then I need to add those split strings to the list.

```
line = "DATA", "LT", "0.40", "1.25", "Sentence, which contain, 
commas", "401", "", "MN", "", "", "", "", ""
```

when I try to do it with

```
lineItems = line.split(",")
```

It splits based on all commas.

Conversely, when I use regex to split, I get all elements as one element on the list. (can not split them).

Is there any chance to get:

```
newlist  = ['DATA', 'LT', '0.40', '1.25', 'Sentence, which contain, 
    commas', '401', '', 'MN', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Thanks!

P.S I will have many similar rows so I want to get a similar result from all via iteration.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the csv library? Is this an assignment or a real use case?

Comment: I don't understand, the `line` variable is a tuple of str. Your answer is `list(line)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you tried to split a 'string' variable. Therefor I assume you forgot to add the appropriate quotes. Is the following helpfull, assuming balanced double quotes?

```
import regex as re

line = """ "DATA", "LT", "0.40", "1.25", "Sentence, which contain, 
commas", "401", "", "MN", "", "", "", "", "" """

l = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', line)

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['DATA', 'LT', '0.40', '1.25', 'Sentence, which contain, \ncommas', '401', '', 'MN', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to mention that, I get "line" from for loop  iteration                      
  "for line in agsData[groupDict['GEOL'][0]:groupDict['GEOL'][1]]:"  , so I do not get quotes which cover all.     I get following, when I print(line)                                                                                                                          "DATA", "LT", "0.40", "1.25", "Sentence, which contain, commas", "401", "", "MN", "", "", "", "", ""              So, when I implement function, I get everything within one quote(as one element)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `shlex` in-built module, like so

```py
import shlex
line = '"DATA", "LT", "0.40", "1.25", "Sentence, which contain, commas", "401", "", "MN", "", "", "", "", ""'

newlist = [x[:-1] for x in shlex.split(line)]
```

Comment: Fantastic, never heard about the function. ++

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to mention that, I get "line" from for loop  iteration                      
  "for line in agsData[groupDict['GEOL'][0]:groupDict['GEOL'][1]]:"  , so I do not get quotes which cover all.     I get following, when I print(line)                                                                                                                          "DATA", "LT", "0.40", "1.25", "Sentence, which contain, commas", "401", "", "MN", "", "", "", "", ""              So, when I implement function, I get everything within one quote(as one element)